# PostgreSQL: create a personalized role for any customer

Tags: postgresql

I am new to Postgres, sorry if the question is basic:)

I need to create a personalized role for any customer already existing in the DB.
Role name must be client_{first_name}_{last_name} (without curly brackets).
Also, this customer can only access his own data in "table_1" and "table_2" tables.

I took ALICE STEWART (id 51).

What I did:

I created role Customer with Select privilege. Then tried to create role for ALICE STEWART and I get an infinite recursion error.
But how to create role for one customer so that he could access only his info in 2 tables?

How to do that properly?

Comment: There is a recursion in the policy definition, since it contains a `SELECT` statement on the same table.  But since your SQL makes no sense to me and your verbal description is too general, I cannot help beyond that. There is nothing wrong with personal users, as long as you don't grant permissions on the users directly, but handle that via groups.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I've changed the code and the description. If you can help I would be very graceful! Could you give example/template of how to handle it via groups?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with personalized database users, but I would only consider that if you don't have very many users. I wouldn't want to deal with a `pg_authid` that contains 100000 users.

I would not play this with permissions, but with [row level security](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-rowsecurity.html). The exact way in which that would work depends on your data. The easiest way is to have and `owner` column that lists the user that can see the data.

Watch out for overly complicated policies, as they will make your queries slow.